# J2ME and mobile phones

Tags: java, java-me, midlet

can i write a MIDlet that stays "resident" like an agenda, that alarms when a certain event will occur( in other words, the MIDlet API allows the developer write a application that stays running in background)? Within a MIDlet, can i use the vibratory alarm of the cellphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no clean way to background a J2ME app that works generically across all phones.  In most cases phones can only run one app at a time, so even if your app *were* backgrounded, if another app starts, yours could well get terminated.

Having said that, you can for some Sony Ericsson and non-old Nokias at least hide you app with something like this in your MIDlet subclass:

```
Display.getDisplay( this ).setCurrent( null );
```

On your other question about vibration alarms: yes, you can use the [Display.vibrate()](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#vibrate(int)) method:

```
Display.getDisplay( this ).vibrate( duration );
```